# using a variable in the input tag's style attribute

Tags: jquery, html

I have a dropdown box with three values,small,medium and large.If the value is small, the text created should be 100px,if medium then 200px if large,400px. Based on this value can I save the size in a variable,and use that variable in the style attribute?

For eg,
 I get the value of the drop down box as

```
fieldsize=$('#fieldSize').fieldValue();
```

Can i code,
           if(fieldsize=="small"){size=100;}
and use that size variable in the style attribute? (style= 'width:size px')

```
if(fieldType=="text"){
$("<input id=inputstr"+increment+" type= 'text' style= 'width:100px'></input><br><br>").appendTo("#fb_contentarea_col1down21");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do a switch statement to check the value of fieldSize
small = "100px"
medium = "200px"
large = "400px"

Then in your append code write `$("<input style='width:"+fieldWidth+";' ... >")`